# Select a HTML element containing APOSTROPHE using document.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I am trying to select an element containing `1'000 g` using [document.evaluate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#document.evaluate). The issue is the [apostrophe](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0027/index.htm). I tried to use `\u0027`, `''`, `\'`, `\\'` and `&#x27;`, but those either trigger invalid xpath expression errors or return no elements.

```js
const items1 = document.evaluate(
  "//p[contains(normalize-space(.), '1000\u00a0g')]",
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
  null,
);
console.log("item1", items1.snapshotItem(0).textContent);

const items2 = document.evaluate(
  "//p[contains(normalize-space(.), '1&#x27;000\u00a0g')]",
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
  null,
);
console.log("item2", items2.snapshotItem(0).textContent);
```

```html
<p>1000&nbsp;g</p>
<p>1'000&nbsp;g</p>
```

What is the correct way to select an element containing an apostrophe using an xpath expression in [document.evaluate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#document.evaluate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include an apostrophe in the 'contains' section of your XPath you need to use it as a literal character and wrap the string to find in double quotes, which you have to esape using `\"` from the outer string:

```js
const items1 = document.evaluate(
  "//p[contains(normalize-space(.), '1000\u00a0g')]",
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
  null,
);
console.log("item1", items1.snapshotItem(0).textContent);

const items2 = document.evaluate(
  "//p[contains(normalize-space(.), \"1'000\u00a0g\")]",
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
  null,
);
console.log("item2", items2.snapshotItem(0).textContent);
```

```html
<p>1000&nbsp;g</p>
<p>1'000&nbsp;g</p>
```